hide specific screen in bottom nav
I am using bottom nave and in bottom nave screen I am using stack nav but when I want to hide bottom nav in a specific stack navigation screen I tried many things but none worked.
<NavigationContainer independent = { true }>
    <HomeStacks.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" >
      <HomeStacks.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{title: ('Welcome'), headerShown: false}} />
      <HomeStacks.Screen name="Details" component={Details} options={{title: ('Details'), headerShown: false}}/>
      <HomeStacks.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} options={{title: ('Settings'), headerShown: false}}/>
      <HomeStacks.Screen name="Notification" component={Notification} options={{title: ('Notifications'), headerShown: false}}/>
      <HomeStacks.Screen name="NewInspection" component={NewInspection} options={{title: ('NewInspection'), headerShown: false}}/>
      <HomeStacks.Screen name="MoveIn" component={MoveIn} options={{title: ('Move In'), headerShown: false}}/>
      <HomeStacks.Screen name="MoveOut" component={MoveOut} options={{title: ('Move Out'), headerShown: false}}/>
      <HomeStacks.Screen name="Exterior" component={Exterior} options={()=>({title: ('Exterior'), headerShown: false, tabBarStyle: { display: 'none }
        })}/>
    </HomeStacks.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>


You can add useEffect on Screen that you want to hide bottom nav, that worked for me, but not sure about the performance.
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({
      tabBarStyle: {
        display: "none",
      },
    });
    return () =>
      navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({
        tabBarStyle: undefined,
      });
  }, [navigation]);

For example if you want to hide bottom nav on NewInspection screen, basically add this code on NewInspection.

thanks for the answer i did it by adding a state for nav in my project by using redux and than set state from the screen. if my screen setNav to false than in my tab nav it simply do this { display: showNav ? 'flex' : 'none', }. It solved my problem if like it you can also do this!
